# GA custom report returns no results when event action and event label are together added as dimensions

Tags: google-analytics

I am a newb at GA so there might be something very obvious that I maybe missing out on and this is my first question here so please be kind.

Backdrop: My company records user reviews and ratings on its website through GA where a user fills in the rating for their order followed by filling a small questionnaire. User comments and the answers to the questionnaire are recorded as the event action and the id for the user is recorded in the event label while event value has the rating provided by the user.

I am trying to create a report in Google Analytics with event action and event label as my dimensions and my metric as the event value. However, each time that I do this I get a message saying 'There is no data for this view'. What is the reason for this?

I suspect that there is no event label being recorded but is there any way to verify this? Otherwise, such a grouping of dimensions might not be allowed by GA in some cases. Is this possible?

Any insight on this is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You should be able to see if there is an event label being recorded by going to Behavior -> Events -> Top Events.  From there, click your event category and then the event action.  If there is not a label set, you will see a single record reading (not set).  If there are values listed, those are your labels.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Brian. I have solved the issue. It turns out that the event label was being recorded but it could only be used as a dimension when paired with a custom dimension.